# Issue with gulp-css-comb : "Please check the validity"

Tags: sass, gulp, formatting, csscomb

I'm trying to fix my gulp-ccs-comb task but I have this error :

```
MacBook-Pro:myProject remy$ gulp sass-comb
[11:23:10] Using gulpfile ~/myproject/gulpfile.js
[11:23:10] Starting 'sass-comb'...
[11:23:10] Finished 'sass-comb' after 5.88 ms

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: /myPath/sass/helpers/_helpers.scss
Parsing error: Please check the validity of the block starting from line #6

4 | @each $className in $list {
5 |   @for $i from 0 through 100 {
6*|     @if $i % 5 == 0 {
7 |       @each $positionName in $listPosition {
8 |         .#{$className}#{$positionName}-#{$i} {

Gonzales PE version: 3.0.0-28
```

SCSS file :

```
$list: margin padding;
$listPosition: top bottom left right;

@each $className in $list {
  @for $i from 0 through 100 {
    @if $i % 5 == 0 {
      @each $positionName in $listPosition {
        .#{$className}#{$positionName}-#{$i} {
          #{$className}-#{$positionName}: #{$i}px !important;
        }
      }
      .#{$className}-#{$i} {
        #{$className}: #{$i}px !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong in my scss syntax ?

Thank you for your help :)

Rémy.

Comment: It seems that the issue comes from the percentage Modulus operator. Csscomb don't like it. Do I have an other solution to do the trick ?

Comment: Have you tried to parenthesize the condition ie. `@if( $i % 5 == 0 ) {` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `@for` and `@if` to `@while`.

```
$list: margin padding;
$listPosition: top bottom left right;

@each $className in $list {
  $i: 0;
  @while $i <= 100 {
    @each $positionName in $listPosition {
      .#{$className}#{$positionName}-#{$i} {
        #{$className}-#{$positionName}: #{$i}px !important;
      }
    }
    .#{$className}-#{$i} {
      #{$className}: #{$i}px !important;
    }
    $i: $i + 5;
  }
}
```

It works for me ( as well as your code :)